# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'X_1' with dtype float and shape [?,3]

Tags: tensorflow, model, restore, tensorflowsharp

I've wrote a very simple model through the Jupyter Notebook

```
n_input = 3  
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name="X")
decoder = tf.matmul(X, [[2.0,3.0],[2.0,3.0],[2.0,3.0]], name='decoder')

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

values = sess.run(decoder, feed_dict={X: df_norm[:10]})

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
tf.train.write_graph(graph, './model/','saved_model.pbtxt', as_text=False)
```

Then I loaded it with the TensorflowSharp

```
using (var graph = new TFGraph())
            {
                var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@".\model\saved_model.pbtxt");
                graph.Import(bytes);
                var session = new TFSession(graph);


                var runner = session.GetRunner();
                runner.AddInput(graph["X"][0], new float[] { 176.75f, 7.95f, 40397.00f }); 

                runner.Fetch(graph["decoder"][0]);

                var output = runner.Run();

                // Fetch the results from output:
                TFTensor result = output[0];
            }
```

Finally, I got the exception below:

> TensorFlow.TFException   HResult=0x80131500   메시지=You must feed a
>   value for placeholder tensor 'X_1' with dtype float and shape [?,3]
>   [[{{node X_1}} = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,3],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]   소스=TensorFlowSharp   StackTrace:    at
>   TensorFlow.TFStatus.CheckMaybeRaise(TFStatus incomingStatus, Boolean
>   last)    at TensorFlow.TFSession.Run(TFOutput[] inputs, TFTensor[]
>   inputValues, TFOutput[] outputs, TFOperation[] targetOpers, TFBuffer
>   runMetadata, TFBuffer runOptions, TFStatus status)    at
>   TensorFlow.TFSession.Runner.Run(TFStatus status)    at
>   tensorflowsharp_model_restore.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   G:\tensorflow\tensorflowsharp\tensorflowsharp_model_restore\tensorflowsharp_model_restore\Program.cs:line
>   29

Comment: Looks to me like you should feed in `new float[,] {{ 176.75f, 7.95f, 40397.00f }}` instead. Also I'm not sure if the `[0]` in `graph["X"][0]` is appropriate. In general the model expects 2d-input.

Comment: @a_guest I've got a new problem. `Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
  [[{{node Variable/read}} = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable)]]
  `